# CNN stuck at 0% accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm learning CNN and wondering why is my network stuck at 0% accuracy even after multiple epochs? I'm sharing the entire code as it's really simple.

I have a dataset with faces and respective ages. I'm using keras and tf to train a convolution neural network to determine age.

However, my accuracy is always reporting as 0%. I'm very new to neural networks and I'm hoping you could tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
path = "dataset"
pixels = []
age = []
for img in os.listdir(path):
  ages = img.split("_")[0]
  img = cv2.imread(str(path)+"/"+str(img))
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  pixels.append(np.array(img))
  age.append(np.array(ages))
age = np.array(age,dtype=np.int64)
pixels = np.array(pixels)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(pixels,age,random_state=100)

input = Input(shape=(200,200,3))
conv1 = Conv2D(70,(3,3),activation="relu")(input)
conv2 = Conv2D(65,(3,3),activation="relu")(conv1)
batch1 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
pool3 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(batch1)
conv3 = Conv2D(60,(3,3),activation="relu")(pool3)
batch2 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
pool4 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(batch2)
flt = Flatten()(pool4)
#age
age_l = Dense(128,activation="relu")(flt)
age_l = Dense(64,activation="relu")(age_l)
age_l = Dense(32,activation="relu")(age_l)
age_l = Dense(1,activation="relu")(age_l)

model = Model(inputs=input,outputs=age_l)
model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss=["mse","sparse_categorical_crossentropy"],metrics=['mae','accuracy'])
save = model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),epochs=2)
```

Comment: This has been asked many times here, accuracy is completely meaningless in a regression task, it only makes sense for classification.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I thought that determining age is a classification problem.

Comment: That depends on how age is modeled, and your model is doing regression anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to decide if you want to do a classification model or a regression model. As it stands now it looks like you are trying to do a regression model.
Lets start at the outset. Apparently you have a dataset of image files and within the files path is text that defines the age so it is something like
say 27_01.jpg I assume. So you split the path based on the _ to get the age associated with the image file. You then read in the image using cv2 and then convert it to rgb. Now cv2 reads in the image and return it as an array so you don't need to convert it to an np array just use

```
pixels.append(img)
```

now the variable ages is a string which you want to convert into an integer. So just
use the code

```
ages =int( img.split("_")[0])
```

this is now a scaler integer value, not an array so just use

```
age.append(ages)
```

you now have two lists, pixels and age. To use them in a model you need to convert them to np arrays so use

```
age=np.array(age)
pixels=np.array(pixels
```

Now the next thing you want to do  is to create a train set and a test set using the train_test_split function. Lets assume you want 90% of the data set to be used for training and 10% for testing. so use

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(pixels,age,train_size=.9, shuffle=True, random_state=100)
```

Now lets look at your model. This is what decides if you are doing regression or
classification. You want to do regression. Your model is OK but needs some changes
You have 4 dense layers. I suspect that this will lead to a case where your model
is over-fitting so I recommend that prior to the last layer you add a dropout layer
Use the code

```
drop=Dropout(rate=.4, seed=123)(age_1)
age_l = Dense(1,activation="linear")(age_l)
```

Note the activation is set to linear. That way the output can take a range of values
that can be compared to the integer values of the age array.
Now when you compile your model you want your loss to be mse. So it is measuring the error between the models output and the ages. Sparse_categorical crossentropy is used when you are doing classification which is NOT what you are doing. As for the metrics accuracy is used for classification models so you only want to use mae So you compile code should be

```
model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="mse",metrics=['mae'])
```

now model.fit looks ok but you should run for more epochs like say 20. Now when you run your model look at the training loss and the validation loss. As the training loss decreases, on AVERAGE the validation loss should trend to decrease. If it starts to trend upward your model is over-fitting. In that case you may want to add an additional dropout layer.
At some point your model will stop improving if you run a sufficient number of epochs. You can usually get an improvement in performance if you use an adjustable learning rate. Since you are new to this you may not have experience using callbacks. Callbacks are used within model.fit and there are many types. Documentation for callbacks can be found [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/) To implement an adjustable learning rate you can use the callback ReduceLROnPlateau. The documentation for that is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/) What it does is to set it up to monitor the validation loss. If the validation loss fails to reduce for a "patience" number of epochs the callback will reduce the learning rate by the parameter "factor" where

```
new_learning_rate=current_learning rate * factor
```

where factor is a float between 0 and 1.0. May recommended code for this callback is
shown below

```
rlronp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss",factor=0.5, 
                                            patience=2, verbose=1)
```

I also recommend you use the callback EarlyStopping. The documentation for that is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/) Set it up to monitor validation loss. If the loss fails to reduce for 'patience number of consecutive epochs training will be halted. Set the parameter restore_best_weights=True. That way if the callback halts training it leaves your model set with the weights for the epoch that had the lowest validation loss. My recommended code for the callback is shown below

```
estop=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=4,
                                       verbose=1, restore_best_weights=True)
```

To use the callback for model.fit include the code

```
save = model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),epochs=20,
                  callbacks=[rlronp,estop])
```

By the way I think I am familar with this dataset or a similar one. Do not expect
great root mean squared error as I have seen many models for this and none had a small error margin. Incidentally if you want to learn machine learning there is an excellent set of about 200 tutorials on this by a guy called Gabriel Atkin. He can see his tutorials called Data Everyday [here.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLs_CQl4mUvI7Z9HnwoeOS5EUu9gyvekjK) The specific tutorial dealing with this kind of age dataset is located [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AnCNBL8c6Q&list=PLs_CQl4mUvI7Z9HnwoeOS5EUu9gyvekjK&index=200&t=4s)

Comment: Hi, thank you for such a detailed question. I understand much more clearly now. I'm now running the model with your changes with the following epoch loss: https://i.imgur.com/N3FeqWA.png (blue is validation). This suggest I am overfitting. What can I do to improve this?

Comment: You are not over-fitting as the validation loss is NOT increasing it has just reached a level that is the best the model can do. Did you use the callbacks I proposed, they may help. I recommend you add another one or two layer of convolution to your model or better yet use transfer learning to get a stronger model.

Comment: I did add the callbacks. I will experiment with another layers, thanks.